# Create whitespace to add textView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, view

I am following [this][1] tutorial, I have successfully created the albums, what I would like to do now is say or example after 4 albums. I would like to add some whitespace so I can add a TextField here my question is:

1. How would I create the whitespace required?
2. How would I add in the textfield in this specific location?

This is what I have tried. The example code has a method to prepare the albums, I have split the method up into two methods as follows:

```
 private void prepareAlbums() {
        int[] covers = new int[]{
                R.drawable.album1,
                R.drawable.album2,
                R.drawable.album3,
                R.drawable.album4,
                R.drawable.album5,
                R.drawable.album6,
                R.drawable.album7,
                R.drawable.album8,
                R.drawable.album9,
                R.drawable.album10,
                R.drawable.album11};

        Album a = new Album("True Romance", 13, covers[0]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Xscpae", 8, covers[1]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Maroon 5", 11, covers[2]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Born to Die", 12, covers[3]);
        albumList.add(a);

        rootView.setPadding(0,100,0,0);


        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and...

```
private void prepareAlbums2(){
        int[] covers = new int[]{
                R.drawable.album1,
                R.drawable.album2,
                R.drawable.album3,
                R.drawable.album4,
                R.drawable.album5,
                R.drawable.album6,
                R.drawable.album7,
                R.drawable.album8,
                R.drawable.album9,
                R.drawable.album10,
                R.drawable.album11};
        Album a = new Album("Honeymoon", 14, covers[4]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("I Need a Doctor", 1, covers[5]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Loud", 11, covers[6]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Legend", 14, covers[7]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Hello", 11, covers[8]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Greatest Hits", 17, covers[9]);
        albumList.add(a);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Then inside of my onCreate method I did the following:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

  prepareAlbums();
  rootView.setPadding(0,100,0,0);
  prepareAlbums2();

...
  return rootView;
}
```

However, nothing seems to happen when I do this, also I have no idea how to add the text in that position once I created the spacing, any help is much appreciated.

If any other info is needed please ask and ill update this post.

Comment: Use Space or View to add a specific amount of space in your XML file

Comment: How would I do that at the specific location where I want it to be? because I use the album methods to generate the albums how would I do it just after 4 albums for example

Comment: add a image explaining what you want will clear your requirment. so paint your desing then add here.

Comment: Abit messy but illustrates what I need https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vL9wnJulKoYVlnX1F1bUlwTDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I suggested adding a blank `TextView` with the size set as you want.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice how would i do this with the XML's provided thats the problem, its coded in a certain way and I have no idea how to do it. Only the first four need to be grouped then split by "my text" then the rest of the images below will be grouped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the `GridSpacingItemDecoration` class to add extra space at the bottom of the two cards that fall at position X and X+1.

**Update:**

Given that you want a text view in there, it turns out not to be too difficult.  [There is a great example here](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html)

The solution involves creating a callback to dynamically determine the column count based on the position.  You will have to modify the span size to return a one when the position you hit the 4th position.

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
  @Override
  public int getSpanSize(int position) {
    return (3 - position % 3);
  }
});
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

You'll also need to create a case in the adapter to present a TextView instead of the normal card view.

**Update 8/19/2016 Added Detail:**

In the MainActivity, add a callback to return the span size according to the position.  We will determine the position, by adding a dummy value to the dataset.

```
 ((GridLayoutManager)mLayoutManager).setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
         @Override
         public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if ( albumList.get(position).getName().length() == 0)
               return 2;
            return 1;
         }
      });
```

When adding the data, add a dummy value where you want the text to go.  Ideally, you could ether change the class or add an attribute to the class.  For simplicity, an album with no name will be a text row.

```
a = new Album("Born to Die", 12, covers[3]);
albumList.add(a);

albumList.add(new Album("",0, 0));

a = new Album("Honeymoon", 14, covers[4]);
albumList.add(a);
```

Finally, in your adapter code, override the `getItemViewType()` method so that your RecyclerView can support multiple view types.

```
// Change the extending class type
public class AlbumsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

// Add this 
public class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      public TextView textView;
      public TextViewHolder(View itemView) {
         super(itemView);
         textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
      }
   }

// Add this
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   if ( albumList.get(position).getName().length() == 0)
      return 1;
   return 0;
}

@Override
   public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View itemView = null;
      switch ( viewType ) {
         case 0:
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                  .inflate(R.layout.album_card, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
         case 1:
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                  .inflate(R.layout.text_layout, parent, false);
            return new TextViewHolder(itemView);
      }

      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
      Album album = albumList.get(position);
      if ( album.getName().length() == 0) {
         TextViewHolder text = (TextViewHolder)holder;
         text.textView.setText("New Text");
      } else {
         final MyViewHolder myHolder = (MyViewHolder)holder;
         myHolder.title.setText(album.getName());
         myHolder.count.setText(album.getNumOfSongs() + " songs");

         // loading album cover using Glide library
         Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getThumbnail()).into(myHolder.thumbnail);

         myHolder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               showPopupMenu(myHolder.overflow);
            }
         });
      }
   }
}
```

You'll also need a layout for the TextView row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: not currently on pc ill try this when i get back on though, one question though, if I do what you suggested wouldnt this create a whitespace for every 2 cards? i just want it so the first 4 are grouped like above then the "my text" and the rest of them all grouped, not splitting every 2 or so if that makes sense

Comment: oh, I missed the requirement for the text in between.  The print was quite small and I figured it just said space goes here or something.  This solution will not work.

Comment: have you got any other ideas how to do this? I have been trying for a few days before asking on here and am very stuck.

Comment: Revised my answer with something that will hopefully work.

Comment: I am really confused by that :( , In which class would I add the code you mentioned above, and how exactly would this case look? I'm just really confused by the recycler view bit

Comment: With a small messing around I got the majority of your example to compile, but I cant fix these two errors https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vL9wnJulKoeXFQYTkwU1U2RkU/view?usp=sharing and https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4vL9wnJulKoV1IzcXBuTGZ3Mk0

Comment: First error is the ArrayAdapter extended type.  Change it to extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>.  Second is the type of the first parameter to onBindViewHolder

Comment: for 1. Do you mean public class AlbumsAdapter extendsRecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> and for 2. Did you mean TextViewHolder text = (MyViewHolder)holder? I have attached my document here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vL9wnJulKoVmMyQVB1V3VwYnc/view?usp=sharing Sorry for the basic questions, I'm good with normal java but new to Android Java

Comment: 1. yes  2.  No, function definition should look like this: `public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {`

Comment: Change the return type of line 41 to `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`